Command line tool that allows deletion of certificate containers on a SmartCards as non-admin
I am aware that one may use graphical tools to use one's PIN authenticate to one's SmartCard and afterwards delete a certain container on it. However, I would like to do that in a script, and all that I find that works for me is Windows' certutil.exe (built-in). Unfortunately, the suitable command certutil.exe -delkey -csp "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider" %containername% requires elevation, which is illogical, since graphical tools that achieve the same do not require elevation.
So my question is: Do you happen to know other command line tools that can do the same without requiring elevation?
It's a script for users on windows 10/11 and our SmartCards (Thales Safenet ID Prime MD930) are not compatible with the opensc 0.25.1, else pkcs11-tool.exe would have been my solution.

Shouldn't the -user option do that?

Yes indeed! Wow, how could I miss that, that's almost embarrassing :-) Thank you!
